# Send Proxy details with trackevent using ApplicationInsights

Tags: c#, azure, logging, azure-application-insights

So I'm trying to send Logs through dictionaries to Azure using ApplicationInsights. Our Company is using a proxy, therefore I lose a bunch of data during the authentication. Right now i'm doing a second thread that sends an Event every five minutes to Keep the authentication up. Is there an easier/better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are on latest SDK, there is a "heartbeat" feature. It is automatically enabled and sends basic health info every 15 mins by default. You can change it's sending frequency to be lower to achieve the same thing as you want.
In Code for Asp.Net App:

```
            foreach (var module in TelemetryModules.Instance.Modules)
            {
                if (module is IHeartbeatPropertyManager hbeatMan)
                {
                    hbeatMan.HeartbeatInterval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
                }
            }
```